# Hover color change for text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

When I hover over the cube I see the pop up.
When I hover over the text below the cube I see the change of color.

How can I see the color change of the text when I hover over the cube?

Providing my code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx7kx/2/embedded/result/

```
$('document').ready(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.cubeCellGuest').each(function() {
                    var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
                    $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyleGuest">' + htmlText + '</div>');

                    $(this).hover(

                    function() {
                        $(".cubeTextStyleGuest").append("<span class='divStockGuest'>Guest</span>");

                    },

                    function() {
                        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
                    });
                });
            }, 600);

        });
```

Comment: What's with all of the `setTimeout` calls?

Comment: and the repeated `$(document).ready()` wrapping...

Comment: Please click the TidyUp button in your fiddle and follow the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('.cubeCellGuest').each(function() {
    var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
    $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyleGuest">' + htmlText + '</div>');
    $(this).hover(function() {
       $(".cubeTextStyleGuest").addClass("hovered").append("<span class='divStockGuest'>Guest</span>");
    }, function() {
          $(this).find("span:last").remove();
          $(".cubeTextStyleGuest").removeClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.hovered{
  color: red; //any color that you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the hover for your text is styled through css :hover, so it's only called when you hover the text. To solve you're problem

```
  ...

                        $(this).hover(

                        function() {
                            $(".cubeTextStyleGuest").css('color', '#cc6600').append("<span class='divStockGuest'>Guest</span>");

                        },
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in pure css

```
.cube:hover + .cubeTextStyleGuest
{
   color:#cc6600;
}
```

or it maybe

```
.cube:hover ~ .cubeTextStyleGuest
    {
       color:#cc6600;
    }
```

here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/Y2MAp/2/

Hope this helps